# UIApplication OpenUrl double-escaping my URLs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, safari

Basically, i'm trying to program a "tweet this" button from inside my application.  Depending on their spot in the application, they can click the tweet button and it'll shoot them out to Safari with a tweet message that changes depending on where they are.

In order to create URLs, I have to escape the query string that I want to put in the NSUrl object.  So, I do this:

```
NSString* escapedTweet = [@"Some String With Spaces" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

After concatenating the base, my url comes out "http://www.twitter.com/home/?status=Some&20String%20With%20Spaces" - looked at it in the debugger and this is definitely the value (as expected).  Now, I create my URL and launch safari:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString]];
```

But here's where the issue comes up:  OpenUrl appears to be escaping my percent signs, so the actual URL that Safari goes to is "http://www.twitter.com/home/?status=Some%2520String%2520With%2520Spaces", which is obviously a problem since twitter creates the status message as "Some%20String%20With%20Spaces".

NSUrl will NOT allow me to create a URL with spaces in it, so i'm completely lost as to how to get my URLs to just include a %20.  Has anyone else run into this issue or found a workaround?

I'm running on an iPad with an up to date OS, not sure if it's the same issue on the iPhone.

Edit:  In a nutshell, how do I get openUrl to open http://www.twitter.com/home/?status=Some%20Url%20With%20Spaces without escaping my percent signs and creating a URL like http://www.twitter.com/home/?status=Some%2520Url%2520With%2520Spaces?

Comment: When you say "my url comes out", do you mean your URL or your URL *string*? Try doing `NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];` and printing that to see if it's NSURL doing the escaping instead of OpenURL. Also check the console log; I think SpringBoard.app prints the URL being opened.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `escapedUrlString` is declared as `NSURL *escapedUrlString = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedTweet];`. Then your problem probably lies in `openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString]];`, because you’re taking an URL, passing it into *another* URL and then opening it. Fix by passing in `escapedURLString` (which should be named ‘`escapedURL`’) instead of `URLWithString:…`.